# How to show credit card details, address and cart items before placing order?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, credit-card

Is there any way to accomplish this at checkout in magento 2?
[image]

Comment: This is likely a valid question, but I think we should work on getting the question narrowed down to something that users can accurately answer.  Are you seeking pre-stored payments for rapid checkout?

Comment: The image gives a fairly good start to a visual representation of your question, but asking to accomplish that image as a question will probably yield some actual attempts at a solution but without understanding of the underlying requirements.  There is a checkout review step similar to what you have above, but I feel as though some elements are improperly placed or confusing.  Let's find out where this is along the line of a typical checkout.  Is this a logged in user?  A new account?  Has there been previous orders?  Where is shipping? Tax? Sub-total?

Comment: It goes like this: There is only one payment method through card.
Billing address and shipping address are same.
Products are already in cart.
So, before placing order, just need to show all inputted details like above screenshot and then user can Place order.

Comment: Okay so we have so far:  One payment method, a card.  A stored card?  Is that a newly entered card?  On the right, I see the `Enter Quote`, what is that?  
The "Choose your preferred payment method?" is confusing since it appears to have been chosen.  Shipping details are missing for a reason, why?  Why are the 2 item(s) Product Price singular with a 7000.00 total ... should this be 3500.00?   Order Details should be in "cart summary"?

Comment: Ok, I understand, let me make it simple.
It is default magento 2 checkout process, 1st shipping address, then shipping method, then Payment method(card only).
So, we just need a 4th step that shows all these details. Then we can place order.
image edited.

Comment: There is not a review process?  What version of M2?  Custom checkout modules?  Did you check any backend settings that may show/hide parts of the checkout?  Did you check log files for any unusual output relating to the checkout process? (Ie, missing template references?)

Comment: Checkout the docs and explain which parts are missing from the checkout process.
The second link is to a screenshot that may show an example of the review process that may not be working on your site.

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/sales/checkout-process.html

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/Resources/Images/storefront-checkout-totals.png

Comment: No parts are missing and everything is working fine.
Just need to show above info. before placing order on checkout page. In this format.

Comment: Nailed the question -- good communication :)  The question would be, how do I update the theme and settings in M2 checkout review page to match the screenshot.

Comment: The "in this format" part of your comment... Do you mean: in this order sections?  Styling format - color, font family, etc?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

This question's purpose has been narrowed down and is more specific.  The author, from what I can tell, is requiring assistance with Magento 2's review/summary section of the checkout and acquiring the customer data needed to output that information.  If I had to guess, the rift is between the data and how it is provided (requireJS, checkout and customer data JS stuff, knockout templates) and the templates to render it.  Totally out of my current knowledge area.

What I have written below should not be followed, as I had assumed that I was more familiar with an area of Magento 2 than I actually was.  This is something I will be more careful of in the future.  The purpose of me leaving this is because the original question has been clarified quite well, in my opinion.  The author should be able to find an answer from people that have the experience and knowledge to do so.

---

From what I understand, communicating with the author has narrowed down the question to:

> How do I update the theme and settings in M2 checkout summary/review page to match the screenshot.  An emphasis seems to be on producing the template code behind display of
>
> - credit card details,
> - address (billing, assumed by screenshot)
> - cart items

---

**Review the configuration settings for checkout:**

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/configuration/sales/checkout.html

Step 1: Configuration checks.  In the checkout options, be sure to configure them to suit the requirements.

Step 2: Update theme layouts / templates, as needed.

Review the Frontend Developer Guide: (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html) and particularly Templates customization walkthrough (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html)

It is important to understand how layouts work in the event they were customized (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html)

The review page template from the Luma or Blank theme should show the proper code, so I am hoping that an update of any necessary templates in your custom theme wouldn't be an issue if you use code referenced from those default review templates.

If you do not have templates in your theme, please copy the proper template file to your theme.  If you have issues displaying the review template, check that the layouts xml files are not modified to remove or update the template file used.

If there are any specific items missing from there, search for a question answering it, or specify which exact ones in a new question targeting the item.  There is a chance that this may be a question to help customize the checkout review page with some additional information not available in the default theme hierarchy.

Comment: just, unable to figure out knockoutjs part.

Comment: Even by referencing the code in Luma?

Comment: I've reviewed the magento2 repository on github for version 2.2.4, and I will admit that I am unfamiliar with this area enough to give any good advice without a broader understanding of it.  I think we have clarified your exact needs based on our interactions, which can be considered a great step toward finding someone on here with the knowledge to help.   My answer above is fairly magento 1ish, which has shown me that checkout has changed quite a bit, and led to a rather poor assumption of my knowledge to be helpful. I apologize for that and will be more careful moving forward.